# How can we quickly tell if $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is decomposable or not?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If we are given a group, say $\mathbb{Z}_n$ (for some integer $n\ge 2$) what is a quick way to tell if the group is decomposable or not? My book merely states the definition of a decomposable group without giving any examples after the definition.

For example, I looked at $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $\mathbb{Z}_9$ and compared them respectfully with $<2> \times <2>$ and $<3> \times <3>$ and wrote them out as sets of ordered pairs and tried to create an isomorphism by looking at the orders of each element. I said $\mathbb{Z}_4$ was not decomposable because $<2> \times <2>$ doesn't have any elements of order $4$, so it couldn't be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$ (is this argument correct?) But I feel that for larger values of $n$ this method of looking at elements wouldn't be very efficient. What's an easier, perhaps quicker way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is decomposable if and only if $n$ is not a power of a prime.

- If $n$ is not a power of a prime, then $n = ab$ with $a$ and $b$ coprime. Then the Chinese remainder theorem says that $\mathbb{Z}_n \cong \mathbb{Z}_a \times \mathbb{Z}_b$.
- If $n$ is a power of a prime, say $n = p^k$. Suppose $\mathbb{Z}_n \cong G \times H$. By Lagrange's theorem, the orders of $G$ and $H$ are also prime powers, $p^i$ and $p^j$ (with $i+j = k$, $i,j > 0$). Note that $\max(i,j) < k$.
  Then the order of $x \in G$ divides $p^i$ and the order of $y \in H$
  divides $p^j$, again by Lagrange's theorem. It follows that the order
  of any $(x,y) \in G \times H$ divides $p^{\max(i,j)} < p^k$, which is a contradiction,
  because $\mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$ contains an element of order $p^k$.

In general it's difficult to check if $n$ is prime (or find a decomposition as prime factors to check if there's more than one appearing) or not.